# How to solve the sessions in php?

Tags: php, session, xampp

OK so this is what I did: I have made web site, I was using xampp sever, I created database in phpMyAdmin, but there was a problem and I had to reinstall xampp, so with that I deleted the database(yes, i didn't make backup:( ), so I after I install xampp, I created teh same database. But now when I run localhost/website I have a problem with some lines:

Notice: Undefined index: command in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookShop\klasici.php on line 6
and this is on line 6:

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
```

I think the problem is with the session, but I haven't changes nothing in the scripts. The session starts after the connections with the database. Thank you

But now when I changed the line above with this one:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0)
```

{

I have another problem, I can't not update or delete any itam in the shopping cart, below is a part of the code where I think something is wrong:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' &&$_REQUEST['productid']>0)
    {
    remove_product(isset ($_REQUEST['pid']));
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='clear'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='update'){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
        if($q>0 && $q<=999){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        }
        else{
            $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number   between 1 and 999';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $_REQUEST['command'] comes from?

Comment: The message is not related to mysql in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing it to

if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0)

Comment: That helped, but I also have problem with the line where is only this: session_start(); How can I fix this?

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\BookShop\DButils.php on line 6

Comment: you are duplicating sessions_start. So take it out from the place that doesnt need it. So for example if a file that is included to current script has session_start in it, you probably wouldnt need to duplicate it again in the containing script.

Comment: So now when I changed it, something else got wrong I can't update and delete items in the cart I put the code above.thank you